# How do I get mongoid's eager loading to work?

Tags: mongoid, eager-loading

I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `eager_load' for nil:NilClass)
```

when I run the following command in Mongoid 2.2.1

```
Person.includes(:game).all.each do
    user.game.dosomething
end
```

a Person has_one Game

Comment: did you make sure that you have enabled identity map

Comment: Yes, I put it in mongoid.yml.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. Just upgraded from 2.1 to 2.3.1... neither version works.

Comment: ah.. my problem was that I used an array .includes([:affiliate, :user]) instead of separate params. Have you checked your association declarations in both Person and Game models?

Answer (score 1):

Just turn on Identity Map: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/identity_map.html

Comment: This link does not go to any place that talks about identity map.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to your Gemfile

`# gem "mongoid-eager-loading"`

But note that it's deprecated in newer mongoid versions